# How to make qemu-kvm Guest OS read symbolic links from shared folder while connecting VPN through OpenVPN?

Tags: vpn, filesystems, openvpn, symbolic-link, linux-kvm

My qemu-kvm VMs are in Ubuntu 16.04 and QEMU emulator version is 2.5.0.

I want my VMs

1. to read/write from/into the shared folder (in which I created ***symbolic links*** from Host OS).
2. while the VMs connecting to a VPN (Virtual Private Network) server via ***OpenVPN***

I have tried mounting with ***9p***, ***NFS***, ***sshfs***; however, none of them supports my above requirements.

***9p*** allows to access the shared folders while connecting to a VPN server through OpenVPN; however, it doesn't support symbolic links. (error msg: `-bash: cd: configs: Too many levels of symbolic links`)

I also tried with some options of 9p like below, but still get the same message: `type 9p (rw,relatime,sync,dirsync,trans=virtio,version=9p2000.L,security_model=mapped)`. I found some bug reports that might be related to my problem:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1460629; https://bugs.launchpad.net/qemu/+bug/1831354

***NFS***, ***sshfs*** support symbolic links over the network; however guest VM  lose the connection to the shared folder once they start connecting to a VPN server via OpenVPN.

If you have any ideas or suggestions, please let me know.

Comment: If any of it involves an internal network and the openvpn connection does `redirect-gateway` or similar, make sure you add a `net_gateway` `route` for the host IP.